# CSS Transform Not Working in .aspx Page

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am writing a test .aspx page to determine whether or not transform is what's needed for another project.

I'm trying to show/hide "divTest" through using the transform CSS style. Here is the code:

```
            <%@ Page Language="VB" %>
            <%@ Import Namespace="Ionic.Zip" %>
            <%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
            <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>

            <head>
            <style>

            .shown {
              -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
                 -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
                 -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
                  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
                   -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
                      transform: translate(0, 0);    
            }

            .hidden {
              -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
                 -ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
                 -moz-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
                  -ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
                   -o-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
                      transform: translate(-100%, 0);    
            }
            </style>
            </head>


            <script runat="server">
                Sub btnShow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                   divTest.Attributes.Add("class", "shown")
                End Sub

                Sub btnHide_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                   divTest.Attributes.Add("class", "hidden")
                End Sub
            </script>

            <html>
            <body>
                <form id="form1" runat="server">

                <div id="divTest" runat="server" style="display: block" class="hidden">
                    Sample text in a div.
                </div>

                <div>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnShow" OnClick="btnShow_Click" runat="server" Text="Show"/>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnHide" OnClick="btnHide_Click" runat="server" Text="Hide"/>
                </div>

                </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

I know that everything in script and html works already (I tested buttons with adding other test classes on the div in question). Here is a small jsfiddle with the specific CSS styles working: http://jsfiddle.net/6TMcS/165/

Any reason why it isn't working here?

Answer (score 0):

*divTest* style has *display:none* rule. So, it is always hidden. **Move** this rule to the css class.

```
.hidden {
display:none;
-webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
-ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
-moz-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
-ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
-o-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
transform: translate(-100%, 0);    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, what happened was the site I was loading this on was in Compatibility View in IE. Once I turned that off, it worked.